# Refresh mmenu after DOM changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, mmenu

I am building the `<ul>`/`<li>` menu structure with an Aurelia template and view model. It works quite well, I am calling `mmenu()` in the `attached()` handler.

But when the structure changes after the creation, some submenus seems to be broken. I am trying to call `menuApi.update()` after the manipulation but still: The submenu which was already existing before is broken - the newly added works well.

Any ideas how to refresh after changes of the element list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not too easy to find the appropriate documentation a the API part of the docs seem not to show all methods available.

Inspired by the *dynamic content* docu [here](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/tutorials/dynamic-content.html) I used `menuApi.init($('#myMenuTopUlId'))` and it works.